# No signature of method: java.lang.String.div() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer)

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to create version numbers based git commits, but I keep getting the following error when I run gradle (this is in the build.gradle file)

```
ext {
    // Get version number and build number
    def gitNum = "git rev-list --count master".execute().text.trim()
    def version = (gitNum / 10)
    def build = (gitNum.toInterger % 10)
}
```

Error:

```
No signature of method: java.lang.String.div() is applicable for argument types:
   (java.lang.Integer) values: [10] Possible solutions:
   is(java.lang.Object), drop(int), wait(), trim(), dump(), any()
```

Comment: `gitNum` is a String. You may want to convert it to an Integer then proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want.

```
def gitNum = "git rev-list --count master".execute().text.trim().toInteger()
```