# Executing CURL in Shared Library Jenkins Pipeline Using `Process`

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a method in a shared library in my Jenkins pipeline. The idea is to use this library and upload files to a remote host. The library is imported in a singleton library.

```
import com.package.jobutil.UploadFile

def uploadFunc() {
 def uploader = new UploadFile(this)
 withCredentials ([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'user', userNameVariable: 'username', passwordVariable:'password)]) {
  uploader.uploadArtifact("${username}", "${password}", file.txt, location)
 }
}

def call() {
 uploadFunc()
}
```

The class that is instantiated looks like this:

```
class UploadFile {
   def steps

   UploadFile (steps) {
     this.steps = steps
   }

   pulic uploadArtifct (String user, String password, String file, String location) {
   Process proc
   def cred = "${user}:${pass}"
   def cmd = ["curl", "-v", "-u", cred, "--upload-file", file, location]
   steps.println "CURL: ${cmd}"

   proc = cmd.execute()
  }
}
```

Even though I see the `println` line in the logs. I do not see the `curl` command being executed. 
Is there something I am missing that does not invoke the `cmd.execute` to work?

**EDIT**

When I use the `curl` directly in the library, it works.

```
pulic uploadArtifct (String user, String password, String file, String 
  location) {
  def cred = "${user}:${password}"
  def cmd = "curl -v -u ${cred} --upload-file ${file} ${nexusLocation}/${file}"
  try {

  steps.sh cmd
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeExceptipon("Cannot execute curl, exception: [${e.getClass().getName()} - '${e.getMessage()}']")
   }
  }
```

However, when trying to use the `Process` it does not work.

```
pulic uploadArtifct (String user, String password, String file, String 
  location) {
  def cred = "${user}:${password}"
  def cmd = ["curl", "-v", "-u", cred, "--upload-file", ${file}, ${location}]
  try {
   def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
   def proc = cmd.execute()
   proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
   proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
   println sout
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeExceptipon("Cannot execute curl, exception: [${e.getClass().getName()} - '${e.getMessage()}']")
   }
  }
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute curl, exception: [groovy.lang.MissingMethodException - 'No signature of method: java.lang.String.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [file.txt]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159148/6309), you need to capture stdout/stderr to *see* anything.

At the very least:

```
def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err)
//proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

Or, as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/adampats/e682c61fb425a200453607a663980af4):

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println sout
```

An example of [blocking call would be](https://onekilo79.wordpress.com/2016/03/31/jenkins-console-script-with-power/):

```
println new ProcessBuilder( 'sh', '-c', 'du -h --max-depth=1 /var/foo/bar/folder\\ with\\ spaces | sort -hr').redirectErrorStream(true).start().text
```

---

```
def cmd = ["curl", "-v", "-u", cred, "--upload-file", ${file}, ${location}/${file}]
No signature of method: java.lang.String.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [file.txt]
```

The '`/`' in '`${location}/${file}`' is interpreted as an '`/` (`div`) operation instead of a string.

Try instead for that `curl` command argument:

```
${location}+"/"+${file}
```

As noted in your [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56640699/6309), the all path needs to be between double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to at least show me the error. I placed the above in a `try` statement and got this. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute curl, exception: [groovy.lang.MissingMethodException - 'No signature of method: java.lang.String.div() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [file.txt]`

Comment: Seems like the file is not uploading the file. Is there a specific thing I need to do `proc` to enable upload?

Comment: @SSF The error message looks like a type conversion error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49711193/6309

Comment: @SSF Do a `curl -v` (verbose mode: https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-verbose.html): you will have more clues.

Comment: I am doing a `-v`. Also when I do `steps.sh cmd` where `cmd= "curl -v -u ..."` it works. But when I use `proc = cmd.execute()` does not work.

Comment: @SSF Just to be sure, could you edit your question with the code you are now testing?

Comment: @SSF OK, I have edited my answer to address your error message.

Comment: Ok, I don't think I needed the `/` in the `curl` command. However, I still cannot upload. The error is: `cannot open file.txt`. Do I need to stream in the content of the file or something?

Comment: I posted another question with the latest changes. Appreciate it if you could look into it too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640699/upload-local-file-by-using-curl-command-in-shared-library-jenkins-pipeline

Comment: @SSF Sure, sorry that was in the middle of the night for me. I have posted an answer.